# how to piping a flite and select for a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this:

[image]

Sample data can be build using codes

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Date = c("Day 1", 
"Day 7", "Day 29", "Day_8", "Day9", "Day7", "Day.1", "Day 21"
), Score = c("A", "B", "E", "D", "F", "G", "A", "B"), Pass = c("Y", 
"Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I write a piping code to complete a filter and selection. The filter I want is the earliest date, and data selection is (ID, Date, Score). If it is doable, I would like to clean data a little bit as it is allover the place right now. The final data might looks like this:

[image]

Could anyone give me some guidance on this. if possible, both base and tidyverse?

my thought is:

```
df1 <- df %>% filter() %>% select(-Pass)
```

PartII:

If date is something like ad date, how should I get the max(Date)?

New data set can be build using

```
df2<- structure(list(Subject = c("39-903", "39-903", "39-903", 
"39-903", "39-903", "39-903", "39-903", "39-903", "39-905", 
"39-906", "39-907", "304-902", "301-902", "301-903", "301-904"
), DT = c("30 Apr 2019", "25 Jun 2019", "23 Jul 2019", "24 Oct 2019", 
"19 Dec 2019", "27 Jan 2020", "05 Apr 2020", "29 Apr 2020", "", 
"03 Dec 2018", "12 Jul 2019", "29 Apr 2020", "30 Dec 2019", "13 Jan 2020", 
"8 Jun 2020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I tried

```
df2<- df2%>% group_by(Subject)%>% mutate(Date=dmy("DT")) %>% filter (Date==max(Date)
```

and got warning `Warning messages: 1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.`. Mine did not work.

Comment: `mutate(Date=dmy("DT"))` will try to convert "DT" to a date. "DT" isn't a date so it will return a warning that all formats failed to parse. You want `mutate(Date=dmy(DT))`.

Comment: But "DT" is the col name in df2. Is it right that we can call col by "DT"?

Comment: This isn't a select statement. `DT` is an object which refers to the column. `"DT"` is a string value that gets recycled to fill the entire mutate vector.

Comment: Thanks. What if my DT has a name "Data Time", How can I get this object?

Comment: Anything in normal quotes is a character vector. Sometimes `dplyr` is smart enough to know that you are wanting to select a column because it's in a select statement, but this is a mutate. Run this code to see it for yourself: `df2<- df %>% mutate(Date=max("DT"))`

Comment: For objects that have column names with unallowed characters use the right-handed quote above the `~` key. I don't know how to type it in stack-overflow. \`Data Time\`

Comment: Right-handed single quotes are objects. Left-handed single quotes, or double quotes, are characters.

Comment: Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @Stataq can you please update the example with that info as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date=gsub('\\.','_',Date),
         Val=parse_number(Date)) %>%
  filter(Val==min(Val)) %>%
  select(c(ID,Date,Score))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Date  Score
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Day 1 A    
2     2 Day_8 D    
3     3 Day_1 A
```

**Update:** More versatile solution:

```
#Code 2
newdf <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Val=as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9-]", "", Date))) %>%
  filter(Val==min(Val)) %>%
  select(c(ID,Date,Score))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Date  Score
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Day 1 A    
2     2 Day_8 D    
3     3 Day.1 A
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I can see both you and @Edo  used group_by(ID). Why one used ungroup and one not. When do we need to ungroup()?

Comment: @Stataq You would need ungroup if you have more calculations after the pipe like other variables not using groups. As you dont mentioned that I left the grouped data. Hope that is clear for you!

Comment: Thanks. So it only matters if I have more calculations that need to be done after filter. If not, we are OK to skip ungroup()?

Comment: @Stataq Yeah, right, also I have added a more versatile solution if you are interested!

Comment: @ Duck I just added Part II in the question. Now I need to deal with the Date with date info. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @Stataq Load lubridate and try `df2%>% group_by(Subject)%>% mutate(Date=dmy(DT)) %>% filter (Date==max(Date))`

Comment: Thanks. There is one "" for DT, and maxz() won't include it. What should I do if I want to keep the record with "" in DT? Is NA treated as infinity?

Comment: @Stataq You can set in the pipe `replace(is.na(.),"")` or leave the `NA`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(Date = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(Date, "\\d+"))) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 slice_min(Date) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-Pass)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      ID  Date Score
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1     1 A    
#> 2     2     8 D    
#> 3     3     1 A
```

For `Date` I believe it's better if you keep just the number instead of `Day X`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
df1 <- transform(df, Date = as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", Date)))
df1[with(df1, ave(Date, ID, FUN = min) == Date),]
#  ID Date Score Pass
#1  1    1     A    Y
#4  2    8     D    Y
#7  3    1     A    Y
```

---

if we need to keep the `NA` elements as well, can use an `OR` (`|`) condition

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df2%>% 
     group_by(Subject)%>%
     mutate(Date=dmy(DT)) %>% 
     filter (Date==max(Date) |is.na(Date))
```

Comment: Thanks. What about part II. There is "" in `DT`. Current codes `df2%>% group_by(Subject)%>% mutate(Date=dmy(DT)) %>% filter (Date==max(Date))` won't keep that record.

Comment: @Stataq I see the accepted output also showed 3 rows

Comment: Sorry. THe Part II was added after that, that is about the case when DT is a date info.